# T-SQL CTE self-reference CROSS APPLY previous row by date with gaps

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, union-all

I have an updatable table of date-value sequence (say `dbo.sequence`) in SQL Server 2014. Dates are unique.

When new updates come I want to distribute that values into different columns in a separate table (say `dbo.distributed_values`) by certain conditions, e.g. if previous value from `dbo.sequence` is less/greater than current `dbo.sequence` value, it gets inserted into specified column of `dbo.distributed_values` or becomes NULL in that column.

Here is the main idea:

```
;WITH
CTE_tbl (date, value, val_1, val_2, val_3)
AS (
SELECT ... FROM dbo.distributed_values  -- get latest values from database

UNION ALL

SELECT
   SEQ.date,
   SEQ.value,

   CASE
   WHEN ABS (SEQ.value - prev.value) >= 0.5
   THEN SEQ.value
   ELSE NULL
   END AS val_1,

   ...

   FROM dbo.sequence AS SEQ
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM CTE_tbl WHERE date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, SEQ.date)) AS prev
)

INSERT INTO dbo.distributed_values (...)
SELECT *
   FROM CTE_tbl
   ORDER BY date ASC
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Seems it works mostly, but the `dbo.sequence` contains gaps, so I can not use things like `date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, SEQ.date)` to bind on previous row properly.

```
2012-01-04
2012-01-05
2012-01-06
2012-01-09
2012-01-10
2012-01-11
```

How to bind previous value correctly in case of date gaps?

UPD:
By the way, I can not use `LAG ... OVER` in `WHERE` clause, I tried. Could it be used here somehow?

Comment: Your select looks quite complex, but have you checked LAG? Maybe it helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another CTE and use that in your recursive CTE, something like this:

```
;WITH
SequenceWithPrevious AS(
    SELECT * 
        ,PrevValue = LAG(value,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY SEQ.date)
        ,Prevdate = LAG(date,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY SEQ.date)
    FROM dbo.sequence AS SEQ
),
CTE_tbl (date, value, val_1, val_2, val_3)
AS (
SELECT ... FROM dbo.distributed_values  -- get latest values from database

UNION ALL

SELECT  ...
   FROM SequenceWithPrevious AS SEQ
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM CTE_tbl WHERE date = SEQ.PrevDate) AS prev
)

INSERT INTO dbo.distributed_values (...)
SELECT *
   FROM CTE_tbl
   ORDER BY date ASC
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```